# Post complex type to web api

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api, complextype

I am trying to post below complex object Inspection to a web api httppost method ,

```
public class Inspection
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int HireContractLineId { get; set; }
    public List<ImageInfo> Images { get; set; }
}
public class ImageInfo
{
    public DateTime CapturedDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ImageData { get; set; }
    public string  FileName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

my controller is

```
[ActionName("Inspection")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]  Inspection inspection)
{
         List<ImageInfo> images = inspection.Images;
            for (var i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
            {
            }
}
```

As long as I post say 5 to 6 images, the controller receives the object correctly and process it, but if I try to post with more images say 10 (all images around 200 KB), I could hit the controller , but before I reach for loop, the controller hits again and this time passed Inspection object is null and I get Null reference exception.

I guess it has something to do with the size of the passed object, but I couldn't figure out where to increase the size ,with only 5-6 Image Objects, everything works fine.

Below is how the controller is called

```
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppParameters.WebApiBaseURL);
   HttpResponseMessage response =
                await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/fleetitems/Inspection", inspection);
```

Comment: You can change the maximum allowed request size in your web.config. Find the **<httpRuntime>** section and set **maxRequestLength** to the desired limit, in KB. So to set the max to 8 MB, for example, you'd write: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192">`. What happens if you increase this max request length? (For the record, Web API assumes a 4 MB default if **maxRequestLength** isn't specified. If some of the images are > 200 KB and you're using base64 encoding to transmit them, it's certainly possible you'd be hitting this limit).

Comment: @pymaxion, Thanks for your reply,  I have tried this already , I have set <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="262144" /> and also <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <!-- 1GB (the value is in Bytes) -->
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>  Initially I was getting maximum size reached exception which got fixed after these config changes, but the original issue as posted still exists.

Comment: Oops , my mistake I did change the request lenght in my client controller, but the actual web api  config didn't has the content length set , so I changed both my cliient config file and web api config file to add <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192"> and it is workingnow